# Sending data using jquery .ajax to generate pdf file

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

I have the following jquery code for a button that works for the most part, but Im missing a step.

```
$('#download').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = {
        header: $('#header').html(),
        title: $('#title').html(),
        table: $('#nfl').html(),
        rules: $('#rules').html(),
    };

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'print',
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(returnValue) {


        }
    });
});
```

It sends data to the print url that will generate a pdf file that automatically downloads. I can see the code generating the pdf in firebug, but the download does not happen. I never really understood the success: parameter all that well. I think this is where I should edit to get it to work

Comment: set async to false in the ajax call and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that "the print url ... will generate a pdf file that automatically downloads", I assume you mean, it includes a `Content-Disposition: Attachment` response header, with the intent that the user can save the pdf locally.  I believe in this case you don't actually want AJAX, since it won't allow the user to save the download.  Instead, submit an actual form.  As long as the response has the `Content-Disposition: Attachment` header, it shouldn't change the page, but if you wanted to be double safe, you could set the form's target to an iframe or `_blank`.

```
$('#download').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $("<form>", { action: "print", method: "POST", target: "_blank" });

    $("<input>", { name: "header", value: $("#header").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "title", value: $("#title").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "table", value: $("#nfl").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "rules", value: $("#rules").html() }).appendTo(form);

    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: This is just what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The point of the `success:` hook is so that your code can deal with the return value, which will be whatever the ajax-called script will output.

In this case you will need this function to display the pdf file you've created, which I assume would be setting the source of an iframe or inserting the object returned into the DOM.